# In bash, what are my options with respect to handling system requests for inputs?

Tags: bash

I have a script that contains `rm "$STDLOG" &>/dev/null`

In the case of the file not existing, I want to proceed, which is why I'm tossing the results.

But I'm not accounting for the case of insufficient permissions, in which case the system asks a question and the script locks up.

Is there a general method for trapping on requests for input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is your job to instruct the command to either skip (e.g. `--interactive=never`) or force (e.g. `-f`) the operation beforehand.